# Mixed Console / Forms application always opens second console

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I'm writing an app that's primarily intended to be a Console application, but some of its functions open / use forms to do their work.

This all works fine, except that when it's called, the app *always* opens an ADDITIONAL console window, into which all of it's console operations and interactions are performed (this unwanted second window then closes upon program termination). This is *wholly* unwanted behaviour, but I haven't a clue as to why this second window is being spawned, nor why the application insists on only writing/reading from THAT window, instead of the one from which it was called...

Here's the content of my Program.cs file...

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CobblestoneMgmt.Forms;
using ConfigManagement;
using CodeLibrary.ConsoleFunctions;
using Xtensions.CmdlineArgumentMgmt;

namespace AppMgmt
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>The main entry point for the application.</summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] _args)
        {
            ArgumentsMgt args = new ArgumentsMgt(_args);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if (args.Count == 0)
            {
                // Run it as a WindowsForms application.
                Application.Run(new AppManagement());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
                //Run it as a Console application.
                if (args.HasSwitch("install"))
                {
                    if ((args.Count==1) || args["install"].HasValue("guided") || args.HasSwitch("guided"))
                        Application.Run(new Installation());

                    if (args.HasSwitch("regedit"))
                    {
                        if (args["regedit"].HasValue("ShowConfig"))
                        {
                            IniFile config = IniFile.FetchResourceFile("AppMgmt.ExternalResources.DefaultConfig.ini");
                            Con.Write(config.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                Con.WaitPrompt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although I don't think it's relevant, the "Con" interface used here is simply an intermediate class for making Console writes more utilitarian / friendly:

```cs
using System;

namespace CodeLibrary.ConsoleFunctions
{
    /// <summary>Simple static routines to facilitate writing text to the Console in color more efficiently.</summary>
    public static class Con
    {

        #region Methods
        /// <summary>Output specified text to the Console at the current cursor position, in the specified colours.</summary>
        /// <param name="data">The text to write.</param>
        /// <param name="fore">The foreground colour to use (default = LightGray).</param>
        /// <param name="back">The background colour to use (default = black).</param>
        public static void Write(string data, ConsoleColor fore, ConsoleColor back = ConsoleColor.Black)
        {
            CliColor store = CliColor.CaptureConsole();

            Console.ForegroundColor = fore;
            Console.BackgroundColor = back;
            Console.Write(data);

            store.ToConsole();
        }

        public static void Write(string data, CliColor color = null) =>
            Write(data, ((color is null) ? CliColor.Default.Fore : color.Fore), ((color is null) ? CliColor.Default.Back : color.Back));

        /// <summary>Output specified text to the Console at the current cursor position, in the specified colours,followed by a newline.</summary>
        /// <param name="data">The text to write.</param>
        /// <param name="fore">The foreground colour to use (default = LightGray).</param>
        /// <param name="back">The background colour to use (default = black).</param>
        public static void WriteLn(string data, ConsoleColor fore = ConsoleColor.Gray, ConsoleColor back = ConsoleColor.Black)
        {
            Write(data, fore, back);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        /// <summary>Sends text to the Console with a section highlighted in a different colour.</summary>
        /// <param name="first">The first section of text to write in the basic foreground colour.</param>
        /// <param name="second">The second section of text to write in the highlight colour.</param>
        /// <param name="third">An optional third section of text to write, back in the basic foreground colour.</param>
        /// <param name="fore">The foreground colour to use for the first and third strings (default = LightGray).</param>
        /// <param name="highlight">The foreground colour to use for the second string (default = White)</param>
        /// <param name="back">The background colour to use throughout (default = black).</param>
        public static void Highlight(string first, string second, string third = "", ConsoleColor fore = ConsoleColor.Gray, ConsoleColor highlight = ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor back = ConsoleColor.Black)
        {
            Write(first, fore, back);
            Write(second, highlight, back);
            Write(third, fore, back);
        }

        /// <summary>Sends text to the Console with a section highlighted in a different colour and followed with a newline.</summary>
        /// <param name="first">The first section of text to write in the basic foreground colour.</param>
        /// <param name="second">The second section of text to write in the highlight colour.</param>
        /// <param name="third">An optional third section of text to write, back in the basic foreground colour.</param>
        /// <param name="fore">The foreground colour to use for the first and third strings (default = LightGray).</param>
        /// <param name="highlight">The foreground colour to use for the second string (default = White)</param>
        /// <param name="back">The background colour to use throughout (default = black).</param>
        public static void HighlightLn(string first, string second, string third = "", ConsoleColor fore = ConsoleColor.Gray, ConsoleColor highlight = ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor back = ConsoleColor.Black) =>
            Highlight(first, second, third + "\r\n", fore, highlight, back);

        /// <summary>Implements a basic "Press Any Key" pause.</summary>
        /// <param name="withEsc">If set to TRUE, adds the text "(or [ESC] to quit)." to the prompt.</param>
        /// <param name="fore">The foreground colour to apply to the base text.</param>
        /// <param name="back">The background colour to use.</param>
        /// <param name="highlight">Optional highlight colour to apply to the "[ESC]" portion of the output.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static char WaitPrompt(int indent = 0, bool withEsc = false, ConsoleColor fore = ConsoleColor.Gray, ConsoleColor back = ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor highlight = ConsoleColor.White)
        {
            Write("Press any key...".PadLeft(indent,' '), fore, back);
            if (withEsc) Highlight("(or ", "[ESC]", " to quit).", fore, highlight, back);
            char result = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

            // Using \r's, without a \n causes the Cursor to return to column 1, of the same line. This effectively clears
            // the prompt and leaves the cursor where it would have been if the prompt hadn't come up.
            Write("\r                                      \r", fore, back);
            return result;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

All I want is for the application to work within the confines of the Console window from which it is invoked, how do I make it stop creating / accessing the second instance of it?

Comment: Okay, I think I may have figured it out...

The application requires UAC elevation as it interacts with the Registry (reading and writing). It appears that, post-elevation, operations are then conducted in a new (presumably Administrative) Console, that is then closed when the application finishes.

So is there a way to only elevate the access when the extra rights are required, but remain at standard privileges otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems recreating your problem but check if your application is set to ConsoleApplication 
**Right click on the project in solution explorer. Go to Properties set your output type to Console Application.**
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBJkp.png)

Comment: Yes, that is what it's set at. If it makes a difference, it was originally *created* as a WinForms Application project, but was converted to be a Console application after the fact...

Comment: @BrettLeuszler it should be created as a console app first in order to make it work. Create couple test projects and mess around with it. You should find the solution. It's probably some setting you need to change

Comment: After a lot of work, it appears that the problem is related to required UAC elevation for some functions forcing the entire app to elevate at runtime, and therefore run in a new (Administrative) console window...